# PHP Adding an option to sort by date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I have a listing site in wordpress where the irems are automatically sorted by date posted (newest first) when you go to the search results page. There are already options to sort by price (high to low, low to high) but I ned to add the option to sort by date (newest first, oldest first)

The developer of theme told me the files i need to modify but wouldn't give me any help other than that.

I decided to try duplicating the code for sort by price and changing "price" to "date"

Here is the code i added into "Search-listings.php"

```
 /*———————————————————————————–*/
/* Sort By date posted */
/*———————————————————————————–*/

function sort_by_date() {

$extraVars = “”;
foreach($_GET AS $key=>$value) {
$extraVars .= ”;
} ?>

<form action="” name=”order “class=”formsrch” method=”get”>

<option value="DESC" selected=”selected” >
<option value="ASC" selected=”selected” >

<?php }
```

and here is the code i added to the "theme-functions.php"

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Sort By date posted */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function sort_by_date() {

    $extraVars = "";
    foreach($_GET AS $key=>$value) {
        $extraVars .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
    } ?>

    <form action="<?php get_site_url(); ?>"  name="order "class="formsrch" method="get">
        <?php echo $extraVars;?>
        <select class="ct_orderby_price" id="ct_orderby_date" name="ct_orderby_date">
            <option value=""><?php _e('Sort By', 'contempo'); ?></option>
            <option value="DESC" <?php if($_GET['ct_orderby_date'] == 'DESC'){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php _e('Date - Newest', 'contempo'); ?></option>
            <option value="ASC" <?php if($_GET['ct_orderby_date'] == 'ASC'){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php _e('Date - Oldest', 'contempo'); ?></option>
        </select>
    </form>

<?php }
```

Unsurprisingly that didn't work, I'm a beginner at php so any advice 
would be appreciated

OK, so i've figured out i need to add the code to the existing function like so

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Sort By Price */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function sort_by_price() {

    $extraVars = "";
    foreach($_GET AS $key=>$value) {
        $extraVars .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
    } ?>

    <form action="<?php get_site_url(); ?>"  name="order "class="formsrch" method="get">
        <?php echo $extraVars;?>
        <select class="ct_orderby_price" id="ct_orderby_price" name="ct_orderby_price">
            <option value=""><?php _e('Sort By', 'contempo'); ?></option>
            <option value="DESC" <?php if($_GET['ct_orderby_price'] == 'DESC'){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php _e('Price - Highest', 'contempo'); ?></option>
            <option value="ASC" <?php if($_GET['ct_orderby_price'] == 'ASC'){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php _e('Price - Lowest', 'contempo'); ?></option>
             <option value="" <?php if($_GET['the_date'] == 'ASC'){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php _e('Date - Newest First', 'contempo'); ?></option>

        </select>

        </select>
    </form>

<?php }
```

I still can't make the "order by date" work as i don't know what to put in in place of "ct_orderby_price" and if I use the ASC or the DESC option values it just jumps to the price options?

Comment: First of all you should check your used quotes in the sort date function and make sure there are no syntax issues.

Comment: yeah, you've some funky quotes happening here, if that is your actuals.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. I am moving on... good luck.

Comment: I'm coding in dreamweaver which usually throws up any syntax errors before i upload the file. I'm not getting any with this code

Comment: OK, so i've figured out i need to add the code to the existing function see edit to main Q